# how do i set an image for a category in admin panel

Tags: categories, images

i want when create a category,choose an image for it in admin panel and my category page seem like below image:

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask]. This question doesn't show any research effort. A simple google search and site search would have been enough to answer your question. Asking a question here should be your **last** resort, not your first. Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry.Does not repeat

Answer (score 0):

Before questioning please search for the available resources. I've found two available plugins:

- [Categories Images - WP Plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images/screenshots/)
- [WPCustom Category Image - WP Plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpcustom-category-image/screenshots/)

I personally used the first one, and grabbed the necessary code from the plugin to implement my own version, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: i am sorry. tank you so much